# get calendar list by using google calendar api through postman

Tags: google-api, calendar, httprequest, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I am currently working with Google Calendar API and try to get calendar list by using postman, but I don't know its standard format. I try to give it the Authorization header.

```
GET /calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList?key=AIzaSyD-a9IF8KKYgoC3cpgS-Al7hLQDbugrDcw HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer ya29.Glw2BZv7G1Yq9uOk1YoDeRt3N6A_QehUexSRriiVc9Vu9Jn5uPeVZMbqa41xuFJtTbal-kZo0USmBw-JtxMnYR8tAFUnVPiSuZMsiKavV0F9u2sZ3KpvZiDUxv3r3Q
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 28c59154-4267-f007-a627-64a19e8bb6ec
```

The first time I receive usage limit error, and second time is Invalid Credentials error, I am really sure that the token is right. Because of don't know that the request is right or not so I don't know how to resolve it.
Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, when you use access token, the query of `key={YOUR_API_KEY}` is not required. Please use `GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList` as the endpoint.

Even if you modified above, when the same error occurs, can you confirm following points again?

1. What scopes did you include to the access token?

   - In order to retrieve calendar list, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly` or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar` have to be included to the scope.
2. Did you enable Calendar API?

   - You can confirm this at the URL of `https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/calendar-json.googleapis.com/?q=calendar&project=project-id-#####`.
   - When you access above URL, please replace `#####` to your project ID.
3. The expiration time of the access token is 1 hour, from when the access token was retrieved.

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: Hi, I have one problem that the access token is expiresd. In my application, I keep it valid by using refresh token but keep using that token in postman is invalid, Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @Park Jay Access token has to be retrieved by refresh token. For example, when you use the API, at first, it retrieves the access token using the refresh token, and then, it calls the API using the retrieved access token. At Quickstart samples for using APIs at Google, the access token is retrieved using the refresh token every time. How about using like this?

Comment: I see that Google have an api to get access token by giving a refresh token `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` but when I call this api I receive an error invalid grant, So is it right to call new access token by call this API

Comment: @Park Jay I'm sorry for the inconvenience. How about using ``https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token`` for retrieving access token? But this supposes that you have already been able to retrieve access token using refresh token, because I don't know your current situation for retrieving access token. If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you very much